# Group by with having on a non-aggregate function does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

Why is this SQL statement:
`select team,avg(salary) 'Average Salary' from orgchart group by team having salary <38000;`

Gives the following error?

> mysql> select team,avg(salary) 'Average Salary' from orgchart group by
>   team having salary <38000; ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'salary'
>   in 'having clause'

With a `group by` I can only use `having` and not `where`.Correct.
The following works:

`select team,avg(salary) 'Average Salary' from orgchart group by team having avg(salary)<38000;`

Comment: _With a group by I can only use having and not where.Correct._ **No, that is not correct.** If you are using an aggregate function for filtering then that has to go in a having otherwise you can use a `WHERE` to filter your data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HAVING is used to evaluate a *group* of rows. Prior to grouping, you can still evaluate/filter out rows *individually*, by applying a WHERE condition to them.

So, in your case it should likely be

```
select team, avg(salary) 'Average Salary'
from orgchart
where salary < 38000
group by team;
```

assuming that you want to calculate the average salary among the people with the salary below 38000 (separately for every team).

However, if you are actually trying to filter out *teams* where the *average* salary is less than 38000, then `having` is the right choice, but you should compare `avg(salary)`, not `salary`, with the given value, i.e. like this:

```
select team, avg(salary) 'Average Salary'
from orgchart
group by team
having avg(salary) < 38000;
```

Comment: So the problem is if `where` *follows* a `group by`.Right?

Comment: No, `group by` follows `where`. Grouping is done *after* the `where` filter is applied.

Answer (score 2):

A `where` clause applies to individual rows while having applies to groups. More on this can be found at: [difference-between-having-and-where-clause](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/)